# UWP Stack Exchange App

Tags: app, placeholder, windows-uwp

A Universal Windows App for the Stack Exchange network. Not ready for use, but listing it here so I can test write access.

UPDATE: I'm beginning to put the app into a very gradual closed beta. Let me know if you'd like to help test.

Comment: Looks nice, what's uwp?

Comment: @UniquekekitteanateUnidoggy Universal Windows Platform.

Comment: Hey, I have both W10 and WP10. Can I join?

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev Sure! Can you DM me on Twitter? (@im_on_17) I'll send you a link.

Comment: Hey, I was about to start development of an UWP app, but seems you're already on it. Mind if I help testing?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Absolutely. In fact, if you'd like I'll add you to the GitHub project and you can help dev. I've been terribly busy lately and haven't gotten much time. It's still in very early stages so you wouldn't be missing much. Totally up to you.

Comment: Yes, that'd be great. My GitHub user is R2D221.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Added you. There are a few things about it I should give you a heads-up on. If you could contact me at my GitHub email that'd be great.

Comment: Hey, there might be a problem. I see a 404 on the link, even though I'm logged in, and I couldn't find your email in your profile. I haven't paid for private repos, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I don't think you should need to. Try this link: https://github.com/RareNCool/Rare-Exchange

Comment: i would like to be in the test team.